# How to call div tag in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jsp, web, modal-dialog

```
<div id="cd-signup">
        <!-- sign up form -->
        <form name="joinform" class="cd-form" id="joinform" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="act" value="register">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                  .....
                  ....
```

```
function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,permissions', function(response) {
        console.log('Successfulllll login for: ' + response.name);
        name=response.name;
        alert(name+"===="+response.email);
        //here I want to call that Div tag 
    });
}
```

---

Now I'm using the Facebook API and I want to call the sign up form, when I finish the Facebook login.

Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by `calling Div tag`?

Answer (score 0):

Define 'call the div tag'? You can focus it by calling `$('div').focus();`

If you want want to open the modal dialog box make sure that bootstrap JS is on the page and you can call `$('#modalID').modal('show');` But make sure that the id you are calling also has `class="modal"` on it.